# django moderation email notify not working

Tags: django

Added **django-moderation** app to my application and it works. But mail notification for moderator and user not working.

Added settings like below:-
MODERATORS = [ 'email']

notify_moderator  and notify_email both default is True. Is there any additional settings needs to be done? Can anyone plz advise on this. Thanks.